# finding fisher information $e^{\theta-xe^{\theta}}$

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

given a random sample with the following density $$e^{\theta-xe^{\theta}}$$ Find maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ e specify the asymptotic
distribution.

I useded $\lambda = e^{\theta}$          $\theta = log(\lambda)$  in order to recall the exponential distribution I showed that $\hat {\theta}_{MLE}= -log(\bar X)$ because $\hat {\lambda}_{MLE}= \frac{1}{\bar X}$

how can I specify the asymptotic variance of the $\hat {\theta}_{MLE}$?
I know the asymptotic variance it's the inverse of the fisher information
for the exponential distribution the asymptotic variance of the MLE is given by this expression  $\frac{\lambda_0^2}{n}$.by substituting $\lambda = e^{\theta}$ I get that the asymptotic variance is equal to $\frac{e^{2\theta}}{n}$ . the solution should be $\frac{1}{n}$ for the asymptotic variance of $\hat {\theta}_{mle}$ , I do not understand why

can someone give an hint?

Comment: What you have found is the asymptotic variance of $e^{\hat\theta}$. You need the asymptotic variance of $\hat\theta$.

Comment: Apply 'delta method'.